# How do I check for overlap with spawned actors? UE4 C++

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I am quite new to C++ and UE4. I am creating a basic snake game in UE4 and I can't get the snake to trigger an overlap event when it overlaps with the fruit that the snake will eat. The fruit is spawned on BeginPlay at random coordinates each time I start.

I have tested overlapping with actors that are not spawned (i.e., actors that are already in the scene) and this works fine. It seems that there is an issue with testing for an overlap on a spawned actor. I am using the `IsOverlappingActor()` function.

I am thinking there is something wrong with the `Fruit` pointer. I am not sure what though because, when I eject during play and click on the spawned fruit, in the details section the `Fruit` pointer appears to be initialised with the fruit blueprint.

This is my spawn code:

```
void ASnake::SpawnFruit()
{
    if(!FruitClass)
    {
        UE_LOG(LogTemp, Error, TEXT("FoodClass NOT ASSIGNED"));
        return;
    }
    if(FruitClass)
    {
        const float RandX = FMath::RandRange(0.0f, 2000.0f);
        const float RandY = FMath::RandRange(0.0f, 2000.0f);
        
        const FVector SpawnLocation = FVector(RandX, RandY, 50.0f);
        const FRotator SpawnRotation = SnakeHead->GetComponentRotation();

        Fruit = GetWorld()->SpawnActor<AFruit>(FruitClass, SpawnLocation, SpawnRotation);
        Fruit->SetOwner(this);
    }

    // TODO: Delete and spawn new food when overlap with snake
    // TODO: Spawn snake segments when overlap with food
}
```

This is the code in the tick:

```
if(Snake->IsOverlappingActor(Fruit))
{
    UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("OVERLAP OCCURED"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of calling that function on Tick, you should instead create a USphereComponent or UBoxComponent on your Snake to act as a Trigger Volume that you can then subscribe to its OnBeginOverlap and OnEndOverlap delegates to check for overlaps of Fruit Actors.

```
// .h
UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, BlueprintReadOnly, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
UBoxComponent* Volume;

// .cpp
ASnake::ASnake()
{
    Volume = CreateDefaultSubobject<UBoxComponent>(TEXT("Volume"));
    Volume->SetupAttachment(GetRootComponent());
    Volume->InitBoxExtent(FVector(1000.f, 1000.f, 1000.f));
    Volume->SetCollisionResponseToAllChannels(ECR_Overlap);
}

void ASnake::PostInitializeComponents()
{
    Super::PostInitializeComponents();

    Volume->OnComponentBeginOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &ASnake::OnVolumeBeginOverlap);
    Volume->OnComponentEndOverlap.AddDynamic(this, &ASnake::OnVolumeEndOverlap);
}

void ASnake::OnVolumeBeginOverlap(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex, bool bFromSweep, const FHitResult& SweepResult)
{
    if (Cast<AFruit>(OtherActor))
    {
        // Do something to the Fruit.
    }
}

void ASnake::OnVolumeEndOverlap(UPrimitiveComponent* OverlappedComponent, AActor* OtherActor, UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, int32 OtherBodyIndex)
{
    if (Cast<AFruit>(OtherActor))
    {
        // Do something to the Fruit.
    }
}
```

Also ensure that your Fruit Blueprint collision component has GenerateOverlaps enabled.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have implemented the code you suggested but I am still having the same problem.

I can get the code in the `OnVolumeBeginOverlap` to fire if I change the if statement to `if (Cast<AFruit>(Fruit))` but this just fires as soon as I start the game rather than when it's supposed to.

....

To clarify, `Fruit` is a pointer to the spawned Fruit blueprint.

Comment: So I have tested the `OnVolumeBeginOverlap` function without the if statement and with a UE_Log message and it appears to be firing as soon as I hit play.

Comment: Well obviously if you cast a Fruit object to Fruit it will return True. The idea is that you cast whatever object the Volume will overlap to a Fruit so you can test if that object is indeed a Fruit.

Comment: You should print out the name of the object that your Overlapping, so you can see whats causing it, either that or use a Breakpoint to pause execution of your code so you can inspect what its value is.

Comment: I created an array of `OverlappingActors` and printed them to the output log using `Volume->GetOverlappingActors(OUT OverlappingActors);`. According to the output log, the two actors the `Volume` is overlapping with are the `Board` and the `Snake`. However, when I overlap with the spawned Fruit, there is no output to the log. So it clearly isn't recognising that the Volume is overlapping with the fruit actor when I overlap with the fruit. I have made sure Generate Overlap Events is enabled both in code and in the blueprint and during play.

Comment: Check the Collision settings for the Fruit, it most likely doesnt have the appropriate Collision settings to overlap with the Snake Volume.

Comment: OK. So I managed to fix it by doing what you said for the Snake.cpp, but also adding a UBoxComponent to the Fruit.cpp as well. Now it recognises an overlap and the code fires correctly. Do you know why I needed a UBoxComponent on both the fruit and the snake actors?

Comment: So, in summary, there is now a UBoxComponent on both the snake and the fruit that are both initialised in the same way. The only difference being that the `OnVolumeBeginOverlap` and `OnVolumeEndOverlap` code is only being used in the Snake.cpp and not the Fruit.cpp. I appreciate your time, thanks for your help!